# What is the purpose of brackets, [], in handleActions()?

Tags: javascript, redux, redux-actions

I came across a [vanilla counter tutorial](https://redux-actions.js.org/introduction/tutorial#vanilla-counter):

```
const reducer = handleActions(
  {
    [increment]: state => ({ ...state, counter: state.counter + 1 }),
    [decrement]: state => ({ ...state, counter: state.counter - 1 })
  },
  defaultState
);
```

I haven't seen in the [redux-action docs](https://redux-actions.js.org) the purpose and meaning of having to wrap the action inside brackets, `[]`.

Without those, the reducer won't work correctly.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a [computed object property name](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#New_notations_in_ECMAScript_2015) notation, introduced in ES6.

In a nutshell, it allows you to define objects with variable keys:

```
const key = 'someKey';
const obj = {[key]: 1} // {someKey: 1}
```

In your particular example, `increment` is an action, created by `const increment = createAction('INCREMENT');`, so that's why you need to use `[increment]` to define a property in your object.